# Syntax error in string

Tags: python

I'm getting a syntax error when I run this:

```
class Stats:
    Str = random.randint(3,18)
    Int = random.randint(3,18)
    Wis = random.randint(3,18)
    Char = random.randint(3,18)
    Con = random.randint(3,18)
    print "Type the name of a stat (Str, Int, Wis, Char or Con) to see its value"
```

It says that the 'closing' quote is a syntax error- since when are strings syntax errors?

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: Why are you printing inside your class definition and not inside any methods?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using python 3+? `print` is a function in python 3.

```
class Stats:
    Str = random.randint(3,18)
    Int = random.randint(3,18)
    Wis = random.randint(3,18)
    Char = random.randint(3,18)
    Con = random.randint(3,18)
    print("Type the name of a stat (Str, Int, Wis, Char or Con) to see its value")
```